# WPF controls not visible in Visual Studio

Tags: wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I created a UI by dragging and dropping controls from the toolbox in Visual Studio and got the following as I expected.

[image]

And then I modified the XAML to embedded within a proper grid hierarchy. Now all the controls except the menu are not visible in the UI. But I can still select them in the designer as below.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "modified the XAML to embedded within a proper grid hierarchy"? Also side question, what are you using for that sine wave and spectrogram stuff? Those are nifty.

Comment: I assume you mean that in runtime you cannot see the controls? Posting your xaml might help. Perhaps your controls are in the background somehow?